# connect timeout=0???? what about? timeout value expired with 1500

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, timeout, connection, connection-string

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conec = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("data source=" + servidor + "; initial catalog=" + basedatos + "; user id=" + usuario + "; password=" + contra + "; Connect Timeout=1500;  Packet Size=32767; ");
```

that is my connection  but i got `timeout value expired`
i changed it to 0 and i got the same message 
but when i changed it to my `sqlcommand`

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand comando = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(consulta, conexion);
            comando.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

it works ok, why doesn´t it work if i have 0 in my connection string? what is 
the difference? i have listen about connection lifetime but i don't have idea about it.

Comment: Setting the connection timeout doesn't affect the command timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
Connection Timeout=1500
```

instead of:

```
Connect Timeout=1500
```

(From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx).)

Comment: This won't actually fix the problem OP is having. As the documentation you provided states 'Gets the time to wait while trying to establish a connection before terminating the attempt and generating an error'. OP is looking for a way to avoid timing out his connection when executing a command  (which Joe's answer solves) not when connecting to the DB.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Connection Timeout, i.e. the maximum time to wait while establishing a connection, in the Connection String.

You can not set CommandTimeout, the maximum time for a command to complete execution, in the connection string: this has to be set in code.